# How to store & retrieve value using the key as one of field in JSON in Redis

Tags: caching, redis, spring-data-redis

I am new to AWS Elasticache and trying to save records in it. The JSON object looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "100",
    "status": "complete",
    "items": [
                { "transactionNumber": "1", "type": "A"},
                { "transactionNumber": "2", "type": "B"}
            ]
    }
```

I would like to save in such a way so that I could search the cached object either by transactionNumber or id.

What is the best possible way to achieve this?
I would like to know if JSON or Hash I should use and what should the key look like.

Expectations is to only see single record inside items if searched by transactionNumber = 1 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Besides hashes (which is difficult to implement in a good way for your example considering the array in the object) and JSON, you could also store the object as a string with `SET`. Which alternative you chose depends on your use case. With JSON you can retrieve and store part of object. With string you'll need to retrieve and store the whole object.

The array in your object makes the storage strategy challenging. You'll need to store each search term as key, one key for `id` (`id:<ID>`) and one or more keys for each `transactionNumber` (`tn:<TRANSACTION_NUMBER>`).